# Shifting Row values Upwards/Downwards and Replacing Empty Cells with Preceding or Succeeding Values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime

I have a data frame with columns containing different country values, I would like to have a function that shifts the rows in this dataframe independently without the dates. For example, I have a list of related profile shifters for each country which would be used in shifting the rows.

If the profile shifter for a country is -3, that country column, is shifted 3 times downwards, while the last 3 values become the first 3 values in the dataframe. If a profile shifter is +3, the third value of a row is shifted upwards while the first 2 values become the last values in that column.

After the rows have been shifted instead of having the default Nan value appear in the empty cells, I want the preceding or succeeding values to take up the empty cells. The function should also return a data frame [Sample-dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0d2x.png) [Profile Shifter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDisJ.png) [Expected-results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5hX7.png).

Sample Dataset:

```
    Datetime        ARG  AUS  BRA
    1/1/2050 0.00   0.1  2.1  3.1
    1/1/2050 1.00   0.2  2.2  3.2
    1/1/2050 2.00   0.3  2.3  3.3
    1/1/2050 3.00   0.4  2.4  3.4
    1/1/2050 4.00   0.5  2.5  3.5
    1/1/2050 5.00   0.6  2.6  3.6
```

Country Profile Shifters:

```
Country ARG AUS BRA
UTC     -3   -2   4
```

Desired Output:

```
Datetime        ARG  AUS  BRA
1/1/2050 0.00   0.3  2.4  3.4
1/1/2050 1.00   0.4  2.5  3.5
1/1/2050 2.00   0.5  2.1  3.1
1/1/2050 3.00   0.1  2.2  3.2
1/1/2050 4.00   0.2  2.3  3.3
```

This is what I have been trying for days now but it's not working

```
    cols = df1.columns
    for i in cols:
        if i == 'ARG':
            x = df1.iat[0:3,0]
            df1['ARG'] = df1.ARG.shift(periods=-3)
            df1['ARG'].replace(to_replace=np.nan, x)
        elif i == 'AUS':
            df1['AUS'] = df1.AUS.shift(periods=2)
        elif i == 'BRA':
            df1['BRA'] = df1.BRA.shift(periods=1)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Okay done, please check

Comment: thanks for updating. one thing I noticed, did you mean `df1['ARG'] = df1['ARG'].replace(to_replace=np.nan, x)`? `.replace` is not done in-place by default.

Comment: the other thing is, you seem to have nice sample data for the problem - could you provide it as text instead of image? copy&paste is better than OCR... and I think this will improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: @MrFuppes I'm copying from excel but once I try to paste here, it still appears as an image.

Comment: Data is in text form now

Answer (score 0):

This works but is far from being 'good pandas'. I hope that someone will come along and give a nicer, cleaner 'more pandas' answer.

Imports used:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
```

Offset data setup:

```py
offsets = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : ["ARG", "AUS", "BRA"], "UTC Offset" : [-3, -2, 4]})
```

Produces:

```
  Country  UTC Offset
0     ARG          -3
1     AUS          -2
2     BRA           4
```

Note that the timezone offset data I've used here is in a slightly different structure from the example data (country codes by rows, rather than columns). Also worth pointing out that Australia and Brazil have several time zones, so there is no one single UTC offset which applies to those whole countries (only one in Argentina though).

Sample data setup:

```py
sampleDf = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(6):
    dt = datetime.datetime(2050,1,1,i)
    sampleDf = sampleDf.append({'Datetime' : dt,
                                'ARG' : i / 10,
                                'AUS' : (i + 10)/ 10,
                                'BRA' : (i + 20) / 10},
                                ignore_index=True)
```

Produces:

```
             Datetime  ARG  AUS  BRA
0 2050-01-01 00:00:00  0.0  1.0  2.0
1 2050-01-01 01:00:00  0.1  1.1  2.1
2 2050-01-01 02:00:00  0.2  1.2  2.2
3 2050-01-01 03:00:00  0.3  1.3  2.3
4 2050-01-01 04:00:00  0.4  1.4  2.4
5 2050-01-01 05:00:00  0.5  1.5  2.5
```

Code to shift cells:

```py
for idx, offsetData in offsets.iterrows(): # See note 1
    countryCode = offsetData["Country"]
    utcOffset = offsetData["UTC Offset"]
    dfRowCount = sampleDf.shape[0]
    wrappedOffset = (dfRowCount + utcOffset) if utcOffset < 0 else \
                    (-dfRowCount + utcOffset) # See note 2
    countryData = sampleDf[countryCode]
    sampleDf[countryCode] = pd.concat([countryData.shift(utcOffset).dropna(),
           countryData.shift(wrappedOffset).dropna()]).sort_index() # See note 3
```

Produces:

```
             Datetime  ARG  AUS  BRA
0 2050-01-01 00:00:00  0.0  1.4  2.4
1 2050-01-01 01:00:00  0.1  1.5  2.5
2 2050-01-01 02:00:00  0.2  1.0  2.0
3 2050-01-01 03:00:00  0.3  1.1  2.1
4 2050-01-01 04:00:00  0.4  1.2  2.2
5 2050-01-01 05:00:00  0.5  1.3  2.3
```

### Notes

1. Iterating over rows in pandas like this (to me) indicates *'you've run out of pandas skill, and are kind of going against the design of pandas'*. What I have here *works*, but it won't benefit from any/many of the efficiencies of using pandas, and would not be appropriate for a large dataset. Using `itertuples` rather than `iterrows` is supposed to be quicker, but I think neither is great, so I went with what seemed most readable for this case.
2. This solution does two shifts, one of the data shifted by the timezone offset, then a second shift of everything else to fill in what would otherwise be `NaN` holes left by the first shift. This line calculates the size of that second shift.
3. Finally, the results of the two shifts are concatenated together (*after dropping any `NaN` values from both of them*) and assigned back to the original (unshifted) column. `sort_index` puts them back in order based on the index, rather than having the two shifted parts one-after-another.